# Will a Canadian tourist visa rejection for late biometrics hurt future visa applications?

Tags: canada, visa-refusals, tourist-visas, applications, visa-rejections

I'm currently working in the US and applied for a Canadian Tourist Visa. Due to an emergency, I had to go to India for 2 months and couldn't submit my biometrics in time. I got a rejection mail because of this. Will this affect future tourist visa applications?

Comment: Did you try to reschedule the appointment or tell IRCC about the issue https://secure.cic.gc.ca/enquiries-renseignements/canada-case-cas-eng.aspx?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My question was does this affect my future tourist visa application?

If you have a valid reason that you can explain on after checking `YES` to the appropriate question, you very likely won't have a problem

Answer (score 3):

*Rejection* and *refusal* are not necessarily the same.

- A *rejection* can be defined as: An invalid application that did not reach the decision stage for any number of reasons (in your case, biometrics not given in time).
- A *refused* or *denied* application is a valid application which has
  been processed and the decision-maker has decided that the applicant
  fails to meet the requirements.

In general, visa applications ask about *refusals* and/or *denials*, but not *rejections*. It’s important to understand the difference when answering any visa application questions that ask about previous visa history. Canada seems to use *refused* to refer to a valid application where a visa was not approved (source:
https://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=1485&top=16). The UK, Schengen, and the US also use *refused*, as discussed here [Visa Rejection versus Visa Refusal (proposed tags)](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1952/visa-rejection-versus-visa-refusal-proposed-tags)

IMHO you could reasonably answer `No` to a question asking about **refusals/denials** and just mention the rejection in the accompanying comments section.

Comment: This really depends on the content of the letter OP received. Canadian visas can be rejected for incomplete, but for biometrics, since a request letter was sent from IRCC, the visa can be refused for failing to provide information, which is a refusal based on an one-time inadmissibility finding. It won't affect subsequent applications to Canada, but only if it is properly disclosed.